# Summing the amount over a specific value in a pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have some data in a pivot table and I am trying to figure out how to sum each number over 40 in a pivot table column, but only the amount over 40:

```
40
41
42
39
38
```

The above should yield 3  because there are two numbers over 40 (41, 42), and total amount over 40 is 3.

I have not been able to figure out how to do it formulaically, so I am resigned to VBA if necessary.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMPRODUCT()

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5>40)*(A1:A5-40))
```

Where `A1:A5` is the range of the column in your pivot table.

Comment: I really need to get hip to SUMPRODUCT... thank you, Scott!

Comment: @ooolongT if this worked for you please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.